# What is the best way to control what source files are compiled in Visual Studio for an Intel Fortran project?

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, building

I have a Fortran project in Visual Studio 2019 in which I use different versions of subroutines depending on what problem I'm trying to solve, e.g. subroutine `col` has different versions, `col_1.f90`, `col_2.f90`. Currently what I do is use the `'Exclude file from build'` through the options menu of the source file, in order to exclude all of the files except the ones I want to be included in the build. However as I have so many files now it is getting more and more tedious.

I've tried googling around but can't find anything that helps. I am a novice to Fortran in this regard, in that I may find some things of use but do not have enough understanding to implement them. For example I know I could use `ifort col_1.f90 ... foo.f90 -o program.exe` but I do not know how to use this in Visual Studio (currently just hit F5).

Ideally I would like a piece of code in which I can easily select source files to include in the build. I think this is something along the lines of a make file, a header file or an include file, but I am not sure.

I.e. I could have some code like

`include col_1.f90
foo1.f90
...
fooN.f90`

from which Visual Studio would include only those files in the build. If there is a better way please to let me know.

Thanks for your help,
Mustafa.

Comment: It's a while since I used Visual Studio, and I don't have a copy installed on this machine.  But from memory, aren't you just looking to define one *solution* containing multiple *projects* ?  Each project has its own list of source files to compile when required.  (Of course, a source file may be in multiple projects at the same time.)

Comment: Thanks Mark, this is what I was looking for! I don't think I can mark your comment as the answer, but I am replying to let others who read this know that this was the solution. :)